# Creating ggplots in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to create a loop to make a load of different plots from variables in a file imported into R.

Some data in dummydata.csv :

```
Time,A1,A2,A3,A4
1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1
2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3
3,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.4
4,0.6,0.8,0.4,0.6
5,0.8,0.9,0.6,0.7
```

Basically the real data would be in a much larger file than this, and I was interested in plotting "Time" against each other variable in separate plots, and thought trying to loop through it would be much more sensible than just individually writing out each plot!

What I tried to do:

```
library("ggplot2")

dummydata <- read.csv("dummydata.csv", header = T)

columns <- colnames(dummydata[2:5])

for(i in columns){
  title <- paste("graph_", i, ".pdf")
  pdf(title)
  ggplot(data = dummydata, aes(x=Time, y=i)) + geom_point()}
dev.off()
```

Clearly this doesn't work. I've made a few different attempts to get ggplot (or just the normal plot function in R) to take one of the variables to be plotted from a loop, but I seemingly can't do it.

Any advice on what to try would be much appreciated!

Comment: there aren't any layers in your plots, do you want points or something?

Comment: but just make sure you `print` whatever graph you want, `print(ggplot(dat, aes_string("Time", i)) + geom_point())`

Comment: ah yep, forgot the + geom_point() in my example, thanks

Comment: @TomSmith that's not the only change in bunk's comment, also notice the `aes_string()` and the quoted `"Time"`. With those changes it should plug and play with the code in your question.

Comment: Ah, so it does, aes_string has indeed perfectly fixed it, thanks both!
@bunk if you want to add it as an answer, I'll happily accept it, as it fixes my problem, using the same approach as I was already attempting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (it is the default `plot` function) :

```
 for (i in 1:(dim(dummydata)[2]-1)){
     title<-paste0("graph_", i, ".pdf") # use paste0 to remove blanks
     pdf(title)
     plot(x=df[,1],y=df[,i],pch=20,type='l') # add options such as axis titles, color, ...
     dev.off()}
```

if you want to use `ggplot()`:

```
for (i in 1:(dim(dummydata)[2]-1)){
    title<-paste0("graph_", i, ".pdf") 
    pdf(title)
    print(ggplot(data = dummydata, aes(x=Time, y=dummydata[,i+1]))+geom_point())
    dev.off()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using a different approach. I turned the data into long format en then used split to generate all plots (both to pdf and to memory)

```
#reshape data first

library(reshape2)

m_dummydata <- melt(dummydata,id.var="Time")
    head(m_dummydata)
# Time variable value
# 1    1       A1   0.1
# 2    2       A1   0.2
# 3    3       A1   0.4
# 4    4       A1   0.6
# 5    5       A1   0.8
# 6    1       A2   0.2

plots <- lapply(split(m_dummydata,m_dummydata$variable),function(x){
  mytitle=sprintf("graph_%s.pdf",unique(x$variable))
  myplot = ggplot(x, aes(x=Time,y=value)) +geom_point()+labs(title=mytitle)
  pdf(mytitle)
  print(myplot)
  dev.off()
  return(myplot)


})
```